# Multinode(1 Controller node, 2 Compute, 1 Network node) Openstack Rocky deployment on Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, openstack

Single node OpenStack environment deployment on Ubuntu works fine. However, I am unable to setup a multi node OpenStack environment on Ubuntu (with above config). Can anyone help or point out the steps ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to deploy Openstack on multi-node environment:

1. [Openstack Manual Installation](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/)- it is supposed to be best documentation for openstack installation. Manual installation is quite extensive, it takes time to manually configure every components but it is of great learning.
2. [Openstack deployment using DevStack](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/)- the deployment using DevStack is quite easy, initially one need to set up the environment for deployment. It requires having a non-root user with sudo enabled, it should have sudo permission.
3. [Deploying OpenStack using PackStack](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/part-Deploying_OS_using_PackStack.html)- PackStack is suitable for deploying both single node proof of concept installations and more complex multi-node installations. In this one have to generate Answer File, which is edited to configure HOST ADDRESS of multiple node. [https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/multinode-lab.html]
4. [Openstack Ansible Guide](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/openstack-ansible/rocky/)- it is recommended to have a dedicated deployment host. for this you can use 4 machines or VMs(1 Director or Deployment Host, 1 Controller node, 1 Compute node, 1 Storage node)

   - Deployment host, which runs the Ansible playbooks
   - Target hosts, where Ansible installs OpenStack services and infrastructure components

Answer (score 0):

there is also this one:
[OpenStack Charms Deployment Guide](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/index.html)